# Hide cursor with easeljs/createjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, easeljs, createjs

I'm trying to hide my mouse when i'm moving on the canvas but i can't get it to be hidden. I've tried the following to no avail:

```
stage.enableMouseOver(50);
stage.cursor = 'none';
```

The cursor hiding works in Firefox it seems. So it's a Chrome thing...

Does anyone have an idea/fix?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I answered this on the CreateJS community site:
http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/1542-hide-cursor-with-easeljscreatejs

I tested this in Chrome on an existing spike, and it worked fine, but it will only work when you roll over content, since it requires a mouseover event to function.

To hide the cursor when you roll over the entire stage, I recommend using @olsn's approach.

```
// Via EaselJS Stage
stage.canvas.style.cursor = "none";
```

Not only will this work better, it will be way faster, since stage mouseover detection is quite expensive (especially when you run it at 50 checks per second)
Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the cursor-property of your canvas directly via css.

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem of mousemoving and dragging

Comment: Then I didn't get what you are trying to achieve: I thought you want your mouse do be hidden whenever it is above the canvas/canvas-area, unrelated to the canvas-contents?